# Computing a double integral involving $\sin(y^2)$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Let $T = \{(x,y) \in \mathbf{R}^2 \mid x\in [0,1] \land y \in[x, 1] \}$ Determine $$\int_D \sin(y^2)\ dy \ dx$$

I feel like I'm not interpreting the set $T$ correctly. Initially, I thought that it would represent the unit square, but I'm confused about $y\in [x,1]$. My inital approach was to evaluate $$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \sin(y^2)\ dy \ dx$$

but even the integral of $\sin(y^2)$ is not trivial. I haven't taken complex analysis which seems to be needed to compute $\int_0^1 \sin(y^2)\ dy$. What might I be missing, this shouldn't need complex analysis since it was asked on analysis II.

Comment: T is not a square, it is a triangle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral would be
$$ \int_{0}^{1} \int_{x}^{1} sin(y^2)\hspace{0.1cm}dy\hspace{0.1cm}dx$$
Or equivalently,
$$ \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{y} sin(y^2)\hspace{0.1cm}dx\hspace{0.1cm}dy$$
$$ = \int_{0}^{1} y\hspace{0.1cm}sin(y^2)\hspace{0.1cm}dy$$
$$ = \frac{cos(y^2)}{2}\Bigg|_{y=1}^{y=0}$$
$$ = \frac{1-cos\hspace{0.05cm}1}{2}$$